# How to set Google Analytics api key programmatically?

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

I can't find how to do this. There's this documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced - it shows this method:

```
gaInstance.getTracker(trackingId)
```

Where trackingId is the api key, but I think this can be used only after the tracker is already configured right? It's not to *set* the api key.

I need this, because my app has to track to different accounts, depending of a certain server configuration. The server will send me the api key where to track to.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using Google Analytics V2.

Comment: This would also be useful for people that use package name rewriting. EasyTracker can't find its resources if you rewrite the package name via "aapt --rename-manifest-package new.package.name"

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
GoogleAnalytics gaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
Tracker gaTracker = gaInstance.getTracker(apiKeyGA);
gaInstance.setDefaultTracker(gaTracker);
```

Seems to work. I have to confirm although.

I put it somewhere after initialization, after my webservice returns. I save it in prefs to access quicker the next time.

Edit: Doesn't work. It keeps tracking with the string I put in XML, and when I remove the element, it doesn't track anymore. But I let it here for now, maybe it leads to a correct answer.